# How to map a numerical column to categories

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to map a column in a data frame containing numerical values (figure 1) to groups (figure 2).

I didn't implement it. Those figures are manually created data frames

figure 1: [image] figure 2:
[image]

The rule here is quite simple

[image]

It would be better if the solution uses `dplyr`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `cut` or `findInterval`

```
c("s", "m", "l")[findInterval(df$Values, c(1, 3, 5), left.open = TRUE) + 1]
#[1] "s" "m" "m" "m" "l" "l"
```

If you want to include it in the `dplyr` chain

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Group = c("s", "m", "l")[findInterval(Values, c(1, 3, 5),
                                  left.open = TRUE) + 1])

#  Values Group
#1      1     s
#2      2     m
#3      3     m
#4      3     m
#5      4     l
#6      5     l
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(Values = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a case for `case_when()`

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>%
mutate(Group = as.factor(case_when(Value <1 ~ "s", Value > 3 ~ "l", TRUE ~ "m")))
```